# Изменение гравитации по спирали

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется спираль. Нужно, чтобы изменялась гравитация так, чтобы можно было идти по всей поверхности спирали (и по внешней, и по внутренней). Так же хотелось бы, чтобы на конце и начале этой спирали можно было бы совершить переход со внешней на внутреннюю стороны (и обратно).

Я пробовал вращать карту и камеру одновременно, чтобы гравитация оставалась прежней, чтобы создавалось ощущение хождения по этой спирали. Проблема в том, что этим методом можно идти лишь по внутренней стороне.

Думал, может можно через OnCollisionEnter определить нормаль к этой поверхности. Но здесь у меня возникло 2 проблемы: очень трудно описать функцию спирали + не смог найти, как вызывать производные в c# (может, конечно, плохо искал)

У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как ещё можно реализовать изменение гравитации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В математике этих спиралей пруд пруди. Какая имеется в виду?

Comment: Никакой конкретной спирали правильной формы (математически не высчитывается). Вместо спирали могла быть абсолютно любая кривая.